# Variance of subsample from a distribution

Tags: sampling, experiment-design, finite-population, subsampling

I've simulated $N$ variables from a distribution $X_i \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$.

I now take a subsample of size $n$ from this sample. Let the indices of this subsample be denoted $S_n$.

I was wondering what the distribution for the mean of this subsample would be, call it $$\bar X_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i \in S_n} X_i,$$in terms of $\sigma^2$. I have found results on sampling from finite populations, but that is only in terms of the empirical variance not the actual variance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A random sample of size $n$ from a sample of size $N$ from a $N(0, \sigma^2)$ should also be a sample of size $n$ from $N(0, \sigma^2)$. So I don't think anything changes and
$$ \bar{X}_n \sim N(0, \sigma^2/n)$$

Comment: Okay great, does it make any difference if you're sampling with or without replacement?

Comment: Note: this answer is only correct for the distribution of the sub sample, unconditional on the actual distribution of the initial sample. It is incorrect for the distribution of the sub sample, given that we have a fixed initial sample.